# outer join to select

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have select that output 2 columns, region and count. In another table (site_to_site_address) I have full list of regions and I need to join column with full list, but save COUNT condition, if count < 0, it should be space in front of region, if count > 0, should be some number.

```
Select Reg As Region, 
       Count (Reg) As Sleeping  
From 
     (Select DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION(sel1.BSC_NUMBER,sel1.segment_id) as reg
      from 
           (Select * 
            From Re.Bsc_Counter_2_Stat_Kpi
            where TRF_202>0.5 and period_real_start_time >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
            order by PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME desc
           ) sel1,
           (Select * 
            From Re.Bsc_Counter_79_Stat_Kpi
            Where Period_Real_Start_Time >= Trunc(Sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
            Order By Period_Real_Start_Time Desc
           ) Sel2
      where sel1.BSC_NUMBER=sel2.BSC_NUMBER(+)
        and sel1.SEGMENT_ID=sel2.SEGMENT_ID(+)
        and sel1.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME=sel2.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME(+)
        and (Sel2.Trf_215a=0 Or Sel2.Trf_215a Is Null)
      Order By Sel1.Period_Real_Start_Time Desc,
               Sel1.Bsc_Number,
               Sel1.Segment_Id
     )
Group By Reg 
order by sleeping desc;
```

I've tried to join by tag but it doesn't work correctly. I dont get full list of regions.

```
Select s1.Reg As Region, 
       Count (Reg) As Sleeping  
From 
       (Select DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION(sel1.BSC_NUMBER,sel1.segment_id) as reg
        from
               (Select * 
                From Re.Bsc_Counter_2_Stat_Kpi
                where TRF_202>0.5 and period_real_start_time >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
                order by PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME desc
               ) sel1,
               (Select * 
                From Re.Bsc_Counter_79_Stat_Kpi
                Where Period_Real_Start_Time >= Trunc(Sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
                Order By Period_Real_Start_Time Desc
               ) Sel2
          where sel1.BSC_NUMBER=sel2.BSC_NUMBER(+)
            and sel1.SEGMENT_ID=sel2.SEGMENT_ID(+)
            and sel1.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME=sel2.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME(+)
            and (Sel2.Trf_215a=0 Or Sel2.Trf_215a Is Null)
       Order By Sel1.Period_Real_Start_Time Desc,
                Sel1.Bsc_Number,
                Sel1.Segment_Id
       ) S1
Left Outer Join (Select Distinct Site_Region 
                 From Site_To_Site_Address
                ) S2
             on s1.reg=s2.site_region
Group By Reg 
order by sleeping desc;
```

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and Oracle? I'm not sure DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION works on both.)

Comment: wrong tag, Oracle only ) DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION its function

Comment: do you want to see all regions from table Site_To_Site_Address even if there are no data returned by the first part of the query?

Comment: mucio, Yes. I always want to see all regions, even if count < 0 in first part, it should be space in front of region, if count > 0 it should be some nuber. But column region from Site_To_Site_Address must be full.

Comment: then you should use right join or put the region table first, also you have to use the region column from the region table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select s2.site_region As Region, 
       Count (Reg) As Sleeping  
From 
       (Select DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION(sel1.BSC_NUMBER,sel1.segment_id) as reg
        from
               (Select * 
                From Re.Bsc_Counter_2_Stat_Kpi
                where TRF_202>0.5 and period_real_start_time >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
                order by PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME desc
               ) sel1,
               (Select * 
                From Re.Bsc_Counter_79_Stat_Kpi
                Where Period_Real_Start_Time >= Trunc(Sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
                Order By Period_Real_Start_Time Desc
               ) Sel2
          where sel1.BSC_NUMBER=sel2.BSC_NUMBER(+)
            and sel1.SEGMENT_ID=sel2.SEGMENT_ID(+)
            and sel1.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME=sel2.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME(+)
            and (Sel2.Trf_215a=0 Or Sel2.Trf_215a Is Null)
       Order By Sel1.Period_Real_Start_Time Desc,
                Sel1.Bsc_Number,
                Sel1.Segment_Id
       ) S1
RIGHT Outer Join (Select Distinct Site_Region 
                 From Site_To_Site_Address
                ) S2
             on s1.reg=s2.site_region
Group By s2.site_region
order by sleeping desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean by "if count < 0, it should be space in front of region".  `Count()` can never return a negative number.

If you want all regions, your logic is backward.  Use `right outer join` or put the list you want to keep first:

```
Select s2.site_region As Region, 
       Count(s1.Reg) As Sleeping  
From (select Distinct Site_Region 
      From Site_To_Site_Address
     ) regions left join
     (Select DECODE_SITE_TO_REGION(sel1.BSC_NUMBER,sel1.segment_id) as reg
      from Re.Bsc_Counter_2_Stat_Kpi sel1 left join
           Re.Bsc_Counter_79_Stat_Kpi sel2
           on sel1.BSC_NUMBER = sel2.BSC_NUMBER and
              sel1.SEGMENT_ID=sel2.SEGMENT_ID and
              sel1.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME=sel2.PERIOD_REAL_START_TIME and
              Sel2.Trf_215a = 0 and
              sel2.Period_Real_Start_Time >= Trunc(Sysdate-1/24, 'HH')
          where sel1.TRF_202 > 0.5 and
                sel1.period_real_start_time >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') and
       ) S1
       on s1.reg = s2.site_region
Group By s2.Reg 
order by sleeping desc;
```

Note:

- If you want to keep all of something, then put that table first and use `left join`.
- Don't mix old and new-style join syntax.  I think I fixed the subquery, but I'm not 100% sure.
- `order by` is subqueries are useless.
- Your query is probably more complicated than it needs to be to accomplish what you want to do.  But without sample data and desired results, it is hard to suggest anything more.  Consider asking *another* question with sample data and desired results to see if there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: good idea, but missing right parenthesis at line 8. And where did you describe s2.site_region?

Comment: @dend . . . Oops.  I thought I removed that subquery.